# Why npm run dev stuck on APP_URL?

Tags: laravel, npm

Today when i tried to run npm run dev in Laravel 9 , it stucks at APP_URL line. Earlier there were no issues.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZC8A.png)

Answer (score 5):

Hope it's because of Vite

try with

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your build. Laravel now uses [Vite](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite) as front-end bundler. It is much more powerful than mix, so check out the documentation and get used to it. Or [roll back to mix](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix).

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Actuall i didn't aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

first solution : Laravel 9.19 replace the mixer with Vite, for Vite Configuration visit the official Doc of Laravel for Vite [Bundling Assets (Vite)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite)

second solution: install Laravel version 9.1.0 or lower

```
composer create-project Laravel/Laravel App_name 9.1.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall and reinstall the npm package.

Delete the node_modules folder. and then run the following command

```
npm install
```

Later

```
npm install -g require
```

Comment: Sorry , this didn't work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).