# Laravel 9.x how to include custom css into home.blade.php

Tags: php, css, laravel

I've some problems to understanding Laravel 9.x ecosystem...
So, i just started with this framework and have question, how I can attach my css files into view?

I've created fresh laravel project and have maked some changes, than I've run `npm run build` (because of `npm run dev` stucked on my localhost URL), and after that I had in `public` folder folder named `build` and in this folder `assets/style.0327f7a6.css` and `app.334e7359.js`, but how I can include them into my template?

I tried: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{assets('css/style.css')}}" type="text/css">` but got 404 error...

P.S I don't use mix.js(it's not included into this laravel instal, don't know why), I use `vite.config.js`
P.P.S I'm new into Laravel, so can anyone help me with this? I searched all google and can't find resolution for my problem...

Answer (score 4):

ok, so after checking some [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72918810/1196540) I find out that now with Vite.js [configuration docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#configuring-vite) we need to include all css files into `app.js` file throught `import` and than remove css file from `vite.config.js`, after that running `npm run dev` will stucked on `APP_URL`, BUT it compiles all files and launched them into openned browser window!
So, after that we just need to include our files as this `@vite(['resources/css/style.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])` into header and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The assets method look at the public folder. So the `{{assets('css/style.css')}}` look at the path `public/css/style.css` and find nothing there. For your path you need to change your code to look at the correct path , that is `{{assets('build/assets/style.0327f7a6.css')}}`